# Unity2018 IOS flickering ui

Tags: unity-game-engine, metal

Our team updated our Unity from 5.4 to Unity 2018 and since then, we have had lots of UI flickering issues on scenes with sprite renderers behind them.

Observations:

- No flicker when the scene is purely made up of UI elements (images)
- Flickering starts in scene where UI elements are placed over sprite renderers.
- Most flickering happens upon instantiation of UI prefabs
- Flickering will continue after instantiation. Has random chance of stopping then the UI is hidden.

notes on my setup:

- UI elements (ui that has flickering) - A canvas, some images, a mask graphic, some text.
- UI is loaded a second after scene is loaded. Loading uses Resources.Load(prefab) followed by instantiation of the prefab.
- Sprites renderers and UI elements have their own set of layers.
- Rendering settings - Graphic API's = OpenGLES2

Can anyone suggest a fix for this? Has anyone had flickering issues on IOS where the same build on android had no issues?

Comment: Try to assign a different "Order in Layer" value to either the UI images or the sprites.

Comment: @SandroFigo I forgot to mention I have my layers setup. I also updated the description to show my rendering graphic api setting as OpenGLES2